# How to delete duplicate tier price for all products in magento

Tags: magento

There are two tier price in Magento, but another is duplicate of first one.
i need to delete duplicate tier price using coding. Working on a client project, please help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. However note that this will only work when the 2 tier prices have the same price only. You will have to adapt it if you want to check for different customer groups or quantity etc...

```
// Load your product
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($YOUR_PRODUCT_ID);

// Get its tier prices 
$tierPriceProduct = $product->getData ( 'tier_price' );

// Remove tier prices with same price
$prices = array();
foreach ( $tierPriceProduct as  $key => $tierPrice ) {
    if(in_array($tierPrice['price'], $prices)){
        // Remove this tier price
        unset ( $tierPriceProduct[$key] );
    }else{
        $prices[] = $tierPrice['price'];
    }
}

// Then set it back to product and save
$product->setData ('tier_price', $tierPriceProduct );
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

https://gist.github.com/manojind/49479d60a2592acb70da5db10dd4a476

We found a duplicate website, tier price, customer group and quantity magento 2

Just edit the product -> Tier price -> remove the duplicate tier price option ( Customer group , Website and qty ) , 
Like   .
You set site1 -> QTY 10 -> Customer group retailer -> price $10

Now next price :-> You set site1 -> QTY 10 -> Customer group general  -> price $10

Problem : Genral and retailer group will work same so remove anyone , If you need wholesaler customer then you can add next option .

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your answer. Could you please your relevant code / snippets directly here, please?